# In cypress-Bdd-POM framework can wrap elements as below and in cypress do we need it or not ..as in selenium

Tags: cypress

Here the code I wrapped like we create functions in selenium for basePage or selenium driver functions. But since it one liner will it help in code management and is it right way?

```
static isElementVisible (locator) { 

  cy.get(locator).should('be.visible')     
}
```

I have added this function, but its just one functionality for visible do we add it for more assertions as well?

also if it is then do we add for this line as well  ..as the code is repeated for multiple step definitions. will be always get repetition of code ?

```
check_button (Text){

 cy.get(locator).should('be.visible').contains(Text)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

IMO definitely not - Cypress is designed to be fluid - that is chained one command after another - like your example `cy.get(locator).should('be.visible')`.

It's much harder to get the test right when hiding the commands inside POM method. Just take a look at all the questions in SO where test is broken because method  return values don't work with next chained command.

These two test lines have the same amount of clarity:

```js
myPOM.isElementVisible(locator)
```

vs

```js
cy.get(locator).should('be.visible')
```

but now anyone else reading your code has to wonder exactly what `isElementVisible` does internally any time there is an error.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I get what you mean.. but just one question defining new step_definition for the same piece of code like in below example
check_sidebartBtn_text(Text){

cy.get(sidebarBtn).should('be.visible').contains(Text)
}

check_sidebartTitle_text(Text){

    cy.get(sidebarTitle).should('be.visible').contains(Text)
    }